# Why do I add a third-party libraries with pod after engineering complains?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode7

XCode7

this is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0' 

pod 'XMLDictionary'
pod 'Base64nl'
pod 'ASIHTTPRequest'
pod 'AFNetworking'

pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
pod 'PinYin4Objc'

pod 'Pingpp'
```

New project pod after the install is an error

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's the problem?
How to solve?

Answer (score 3):

After installing CocoaPods , you must re-open your project using `*****.xcworkspace` file , NOT `****.xcodeproj` file. Otherwise you would get this error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .
Open xcworkspace of course.
When XCode6 not met this issue.
Today updated XCode7 then added in the original project a third-party library to this wrong.
Then use XCode7 to rebuild a new project.
Use this Podfile to install or the problem.
For nothing...
No more detailed error message...

Comment: Try removing all libraries and see if it compiles. If it does, add libraries one by one to identify which library is causing the error.